# Сортировка массива через конвертацию числа

Tags: python

Необходимо отсортировать массив чисел который вводится пользователем по возрастанию  по первой цифре числа.
Пример: не отсортированный массив 6, 75, 123, 999 . Отсортированный массив 123, 6, 75, 999 .
На ум приходит только решению,  через конвертацию числа в строку, и нахождению первого элемента строки, и посредством сравнения обратно сконвертированого числа с каждым элементом массива сделать сортировку.
Как решить данную задачу альтернативным методом ?

Comment: делите число на 10, пока не получится цифра, по ней сортируете. либо сразу делить на 10 в степени десятичного логарифма .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно всё без перевода в строку. Матушка-рекурсия и математика.

```
my_list = [6, 75, 999, 123]

def renum(n):
    if n > 9:
        return renum(n//10)
    else:
        return n

my_list.sort(key=lambda x: renum(x))

print(my_list)
```

Comment: Зачем рекурсия, когда можно без неё :)  while n > 9: n //= 10 тогда уж

Comment: Кстати, это самый быстрый способ получится из представленных тут пока что, как ни странно :)

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, без перевода в строку здесь никак, можно сделать это, например, так:

```
a = [6, 75, 123, 999]
a.sort(key=lambda x: str(x)[0])
print(a)
```

---

```
[123, 6, 75, 999]
```

Comment: int тут лишний, можно ускорить в полтора раза, если его убрать :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, точно, вы правы :)